# Minimum swaps necessary for every person to meet every other person at every location

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-optimization, combinatorial-designs

#### The setting:

- There are 9 people.
- There are 3 locations.
- At any time, there are 3 people at each location.
- People can only swap locations at the same time.

#### The goal:

- Every person visits each location once.
- Every person meets each person at least once.
- At each swap, one person stays at the location.

#### Example:

The numbers in the table below represent which person is at which location. e.g. in iteration 1, persons 1, 2, and 3 are at location 1. All goals are met in this example, but can it be done in fewer iterations?

| Iteration | Location 1 | Location 2 | Location 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1, 2, 3 | 4, 5, 6 | 7, 8, 9 |
| 2 | 4, 2, 9 | 1, 5, 7 | 3, 8, 6 |
| 3 | 4, 1, 8 | 2, 6, 7 | 3, 9, 5 |
| 4 | 4, 3, 7 | 2, 5, 8 | 1, 9, 6 |
| 5 | 5, 6, 7 | 3, 8, 9 | 1, 2, 4 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do it in fewer iterations. There are $\binom 92=36$ pairs of people, and each round allows at most $9$ of the pairs to meet, so you need at least four rounds. However, we can show four rounds are impossible.

Without loss of generality, the first round is $123\mid 456\mid 789$. Every location needs someone to stick around for the second round, WLOG the people who remain are $1,4,$ and $7$. Since $1$ needs to visit every location, $1$ needs to visit locations $2$ and $3$ during rounds $3$ and $4$. WLOG, $1$ visits location $2$ first.

So far, we have the following partial schedule:

| Iteration | Location 1 | Location 2 | Location 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1, 2, 3 | 4, 5, 6 | 7, 8, 9 |
| 2 | 1, | 4, | 7, |
| 3 |  | 1, |  |
| 4 |  |  | 1, |

At some point, $1$ and $4$ need to meet. They cannot meet in round $3$, since then $4$ would only have time to visit two locations. So they must meet in round $4$. This means that the group that meets at round $4$ and location $3$ is $\{1,4,x\}$ for some $x$.

Since every round causes at most $9$ new pairs of people to meet, and there are $36$ pairs of people who need to meet, *there cannot be any repetitions of pairs of people meeting*, else the schedule would not be efficient enough for all pairs to meet. Since each pair of people can only meet once, $x$ cannot be $2$ or $3$ (since $1$ met $2$ and $3$ in round $1$), and $x$ cannot be $5$ or $6$ (since $4$ met $5$ and $6$ in round $1$), so $x$ must be $7$, $8$ or $9$. However, if $x$ was $7$, then $7$ would visit at most $2$ locations, so $x$ must be $8$ or $9$. WLOG, $x=8$. Let us update our partial schedule:

| Iteration | Location 1 | Location 2 | Location 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1, 2, 3 | 4, 5, 6 | 7, 8, 9 |
| 2 | 1, | 4, | 7, |
| 3 |  | 1, |  |
| 4 |  |  | 1, 4, 8 |

At last, we get our contradiction. Consider the location of $8$ in round $2$.

- If $8$ is in location $1$ in round $2$, then $1$ and $8$ would meet twice.
- If $8$ is in location $2$ in round $2$, then $4$ and $8$ would meet twice.
- If $8$ is in location $3$ in round $2$, then $7$ and $8$ would meet twice.

There is no possible place for $8$ in round $2$, so no four-round schedule is possible.

Comment: With four rounds, the minimum number of uncovered pairs turns out to be $12$.